# Silent kick stand? How to?

Tags: mountain-bike, noise, clicking, kickstand

Is there any way to make a kick stand silent during riding on uneven, stone roads and paths? I am actually refering to the "cube kick stand" for the "cube acid, kick stand ready, 2017" mtbike.

Comment: Try by removing it. Kickstands are good for city riding but dangerous on rough terrain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I asked.

Comment: Can you figure out what part is loose?  1) the clamp onto the bike  or 2) the detent that holds the kickstand up  or 3) maybe yours has a length-adjustable leg which is moving.

Comment: @AlexPar It's good advice and, technically, it answers your question: if your kickstand is sitting in your garage while you ride your bike, it's silent. People who have kick stands tend to believe they need them but, in most cases, they're completely unnecessary. In an urban area, there's always something to lean your bike against; in a rural area, you can always lay it down on grass or something like that. There's basically no need to have a bike stand up on its own, ever.

Comment: As long as I say I need it, then I do need it. I don't mind if you don't, but my question is based in my needs and there is no sense for somebody to try to change my mind instead of answering my question.

Comment: @AlexPar quite right

Comment: @AlexPar There's a distinction between "need" and "want".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: there is also a difference between "unnecessary" and "a bad idea". There are a great many things that are "unnecessary", but nonetheless can provide significant value or convenience. Probably 95% of aftermarket bike stuff is stuff that's not strictly necessary.

Comment: @whatsisname Kick stands are a bad idea on rough terrain because they can be jarred into deploying, which causes a crash. Now, you can also argue that handlebars can snag on things, which causes a crash. That's where the necessary/unnecessary distinction comes in.

Comment: @AlexPar Sorry Sir to have stepped on your small/big toe but I stand further with my opinion. :-D

Answer (score 4):

Presumably this is the stand you have: https://www.cube.eu/en/equipment/components/kickstands/product/cube-kickstand-cubestand-cmpt-black/

You need to determine what part of the kickstand is loose and moving when you go over bumps. You can inspect the stand, but also try dropping the bike onto it's tires from 6"/10cm off the ground. That's enough to reveal things that rattle. Bear in mind that something else may be rattling, it's hard to hear where noises come from when riding.

Perhaps the mechanism attaching the stand to the bike has come loose. Is the extendable leg rattling? If so maybe it can be solved by pushing the leg all the way in when you'll be riding bumpy roads.

Comment: Note that one option is to tie the stand to the chain stay with a Velcro strap.